# Description for category names of Mozilla Shavar blacklist

Tags: firefox, privacy, tracking, privacy-protection

Looking at the [Mozilla Shavar blacklist](https://github.com/mozilla-services/shavar-prod-lists), which is used for tracking protection (ex. in Mozilla Firefox), the services are grouped in several categories:

```
Email
EmailStrict
Advertising
Content
Analytics
FingerprintingInvasive
FingerprintingGeneral
Social
Cryptomining
```

Most of them are self-explaining. But for `Content` I've no clue what it (technically) means. Can someone explain what this category is for and why it is different from `Advertising` and `Analytics`?

Comment: "Content" - Adult rated sites? PG rated sites?

Comment: I don't think so. Looking into the raw JSON, one can see, that Mozilla puts companies like Adobe, Facebook, Google and Salesforce into this category. So it seems related to the tracking technique that is used.